# Mock Gps Not working

Tags: java, android

I created an application for outdoor navigation. But to demonstrate I used mock GPS. But it's ot working now. In my application this class has 2 buttons. When user select pause button it auto display as start. Then again user select start button then it will generate exception. This is the code i try to develop:

```
public class PathRecorderPauseActivity extends Activity implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnLongClickListener, OnClickListener,
    OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

private Button btnPause;
private TextView text;
private LocationManager manager;
private Button btnStop;
private boolean stop = true;
private LocationListener listener;
private boolean triger = true;
private boolean isIn = false;
private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button btnShowDetails;
private MockGpsProvider mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
private Integer mMockGpsProviderIndex = 0;

private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;
public static final String LOG_TAG = "MockGpsProviderActivity";
private static final String MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX = "GpsMockProviderIndex";

// vibrator
//private Vibrator myVib;

private String speechText = "";
private TextToSpeech tts;
private ShakeListener mShaker;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private static final String TAG = "VoiceRecognition";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pathrecorderpause);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    int width = display.getWidth();

    if (savedInstanceState instanceof Bundle) {
        mMockGpsProviderIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(
                MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, 0);
    }

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    dbHelper = new DbConnect(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    /*
     * db.execSQL("DROP TABLE tblPathInfo");
     * db.execSQL("DROP TABLE tblPath");
     */

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + "tblPath(pathId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "source VARCHAR, "
            + "destination VARCHAR, " + "startTime VARCHAR, "
            + "endTime VARCHAR, " + "distance DOUBLE);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + "tblPathInfo(infoId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "pathId INTERGER, " + "lat DOUBLE, " + "lon DOUBLE, "
            + "curLocation VARCHAR);");

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    String curentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    Log.d("Time", curentDateandTime);

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tblPath (pathId,distance,startTime) VALUES ((SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath) + 1 ,0,'"
            + curentDateandTime + "')");

    db.close();

    btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    btnPause.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    // btnPause.setOnTouchListener(this);

    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnStop.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    // btnStop.setOnTouchListener(this);


    // vibration
    /*myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    int dot = 200;
    int long_gap = 100;
    long[] pattern = { 0, // Start immediately
            dot, long_gap, dot, long_gap, dot, long_gap, dot, long_gap

    };*/

    // Only perform this pattern one time (-1 means "do not repeat")
    //myVib.vibrate(pattern, -1);
    // vibration closed

    mShaker = new ShakeListener(this);
    mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener() {
        public void onShake() {
            if (tts.isSpeaking()) {
                tts.stop();
            }
        }
    });

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(height) + "X" + String.valueOf(width));
    View vw = (View) findViewById(R.id.view1); // middle one
    vw.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                Log.d("TouchTest", "ACTION_MOVE");
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(event.getX()) + " X "
                        + String.valueOf(event.getY()));

                if ((event.getX() >= 15 && event.getX() <= 305)
                        && (event.getY() >= 60 && event.getY() <= 224)) {
                    if (isIn == false) {
                        PathRecorderActivity.tts.speak("Stop",
                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        isIn = true;
                    }

                }

                else if ((event.getX() >= 15 && event.getX() <= 310)
                        && (event.getY() >= 245 && event.getY() <= 403)) {
                    if (isIn == false) {
                        PathRecorderActivity.tts.speak("Pause",
                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        isIn = true;
                    }

                }

                else {
                    isIn = false;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

    });


    if (AppConstants.VoiceOrTouch.vot == 1) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(
                RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);

        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            // startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }


    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listener = new LocationListener() {

        private JSONObject currentLocJSON;
        private String currentLocationInfo;
        private String locationName;

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.i("currentLocationInfo -- ", location.getLatitude() + " : "
                    + location.getLongitude());
            /*
             * text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
             * 
             * text.setText("Latitude : " + location.getLatitude() +
             * "X Longitude : " + location.getLongitude());
             */
            currentLocationInfo = MapConstants.GetConstantLocationInfo(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            //if (currentLocationInfo == null) {
            //  currentLocJSON = getLocationInfoAsJSON(
            //          location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            //  currentLocationInfo = getLocationInfo(currentLocJSON);
            //}

            Log.i("currentLocationInfo -- ", currentLocationInfo);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocationInfo,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            insertLocationDatailsToDB(location, currentLocationInfo);

        }

        private void insertLocationDatailsToDB(Location location,
                String currentLocationInfo) {
            double latOld = 0;
            double lonOld = 0;
            double newDistance;

            text.setText("Current Location = " + currentLocationInfo
                    + " | Latitude = " + location.getLatitude()
                    + " | Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
            // Log.i("insertLocationDatailsToDB", "4");

            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            // Log.i("insertLocationDatailsToDB", "5");

            // check if there a source name inserted pathTbl
            if (triger == true) {
                // Log.i("insertLocationDatailsToDB", "6");
                db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPath SET source = '"
                        + currentLocationInfo
                        + "'  WHERE pathId = (SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath);");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tblPathInfo (infoId,pathId,lat,lon,curLocation) VALUES ((SELECT max(infoId) FROM tblPathInfo) + 1 ,"
                        + "(SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath),"
                        + location.getLatitude()
                        + ", "
                        + location.getLongitude()
                        + ",'"
                        + currentLocationInfo + "'  )");
                triger = false;
            } else {
                // Log.i("insertLocationDatailsToDB", "7");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tblPathInfo (infoId,pathId,lat,lon,curLocation) VALUES ((SELECT max(infoId) FROM tblPathInfo) + 1 ,"
                        + "(SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath),"
                        + location.getLatitude()
                        + ", "
                        + location.getLongitude()
                        + ",'"
                        + currentLocationInfo + "'  )");

                Cursor cur = db
                        .rawQuery(
                                "SELECT lat,lon,pathId FROM tblPathInfo WHERE pathId = (SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath) AND "
                                        + "infoId=((SELECT max(infoId) FROM tblPathInfo) - 1);",
                                null);
                if (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    latOld = cur.getDouble(0);
                    lonOld = cur.getDouble(1);
                    AppConstants.DataConstants.SELECTED_PATH_ID = cur
                            .getString(2);
                }
                Location oldLoc = new Location("oldLocation");
                oldLoc.setLatitude(latOld);
                oldLoc.setLongitude(lonOld);

                newDistance = location.distanceTo(oldLoc);
                db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPath SET  distance = distance + "
                        + newDistance
                        + "  WHERE pathId = (SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath);");
            }
            db.close();

        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param currentLocJSON
         *            this is JSON object which contains the location
         *            details according to the passed Latitude & Longitude
         *            value..
         * @return String result which should be the location name which we
         *         requested and returned as JSON from google api's We split
         *         the most suitable result from the JSON request
         */
        private String getLocationInfo(JSONObject currentLocJSON) {
            JSONArray jArray = null;
            try {

                jArray = currentLocJSON.getJSONArray("results");

                // Check is there any details available by checking the JSON
                // request
                if (jArray.length() != 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        locationName = jArray.getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONArray("address_components")
                                .getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name");

                        if (locationName != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    locationName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                text.setText("JSONException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return locationName;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param latitude
         * @param longitude
         * @return JSON Object This function get latitude & longitude and
         *         pass them in to the maps.googleapis.com server and get
         *         location details as JSON result
         */
        private JSONObject getLocationInfoAsJSON(double latitude,
                double longitude) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                                + latitude + "," + longitude
                                + "&sensor=true");

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                response = client.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                text.setText("ClientProtocolException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                text.setText("IOException");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                text.setText("Exception");
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                text.setText("JSONException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
    };

    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                listener);
    } else if (!manager
            .isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
        manager.addTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, false,
                false, false, false, true, false, false, 0, 5);
        manager.setTestProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER,
                true);
    }

    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, listener);

        try {
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d("LeeInuka", "1");
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("mock_gps_data.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            Log.d("LeeInuka", "2");
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(line);
                // Log.d("Lee", line);
                Log.d("LeeInuka", "3");
            }

            Log.d("LeeInuka", "4");
            String[] coordinates = new String[data.size()];
            data.toArray(coordinates);

            mMockGpsProviderTask = new MockGpsProvider();
            mMockGpsProviderTask.execute(coordinates);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MOKE", "........");
        }
    }

    // manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 10,
    // listener);

    /***
     * Pause/Start Recording Button
     */
    btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    /***
     * Stop Recording Button
     */
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnShowDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // store where we are before closing the app, so we can skip to the
    // location right away when restarting
    savedInstanceState.putInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX,
            mMockGpsProviderIndex);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

// Tharika changed vibration

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnPause:
        tts.speak("Pause", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        // myVib.vibrate(100);
        break;

    case R.id.btnStop:
        tts.speak("Stop", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        // myVib.vibrate(100);
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }
}

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnPause:

        if (stop) {
            stop = false;
            // Log.d("btn_stop", "Path Recording has been Paused");
            btnPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_start);
            tts.speak("Path Recording has been Paused",
                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Path Recording has been Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            manager.removeUpdates(listener);

        }

        else {
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
            btnPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
            tts.speak("Path Recording has been started",
                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            stop = true;
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btnStop:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Path Recording has been Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tts.speak("Path Recording has been Stoped",
                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        try {
            mMockGpsProviderTask.cancel(true);
            mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager
                    .removeTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        manager.removeUpdates(listener);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf_1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

        String curentEndDateandTime = sdf_1.format(new Date());

        db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPath SET destination = (SELECT curLocation FROM tblPathInfo WHERE infoId = (SELECT max(infoId) FROM tblPathInfo) ) , endTime = '"
                + curentEndDateandTime
                + "' WHERE pathId = (SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath);");

        db.close();

        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cu2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath;", null);

        if (cu2.moveToNext()) {

            AppConstants.DataConstants.SELECTED_PATH_ID = cu2.getString(0);
        }

        db.close();

        startActivity(new Intent(PathRecorderPauseActivity.this,
                ShortCutPathActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Path has been recorded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        finish();
        break;

    case R.id.button1:

        String testData = "";
        String testData1 = "";

        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cu = db
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM tblPathInfo WHERE pathId = (SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath);",
                        null);

        while (cu.moveToNext()) {

            testData = testData + " ********** currentLoc : "
                    + cu.getString(4) + " & lat : " + cu.getString(2)
                    + " & lon : " + cu.getString(3);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), testData,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Cursor cu1 = db
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM tblPath WHERE pathId = (SELECT max(pathId) FROM tblPath);",
                        null);

        if (cu1.moveToNext()) {
            testData1 = cu1.getString(0) + " | " + cu1.getString(1) + " | "
                    + " | " + cu1.getString(2) + " | " + cu1.getString(3)
                    + " | " + cu1.getString(4) + " | " + cu1.getString(5);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), testData1,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db.close();

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    if (AppConstants.VoiceOrTouch.vot == 0) {
        tts.speak(
                "Service is runing.Panel 3.It has two buttons.First button is Stop"
                        + "It is top on the screen.Second button is Pause.It is bottom on the screen."
                        + "If you choose stop it will stop the recording."
                        + "And if you choose Pause it will temporally stop the recording."
                        + "Please touch or give single tap to identify the buttons."
                        + "Please long press the button that you want to navigate.",
                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    else if (AppConstants.VoiceOrTouch.vot == 1) {
        speechText = "Panel 3.It has two options as stop and paues."
                + "Please say stop to stop the recording path."
                + "Please say pause to pause the recording path.";

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "ourVoice");
        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
        tts.speak(speechText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, hm);
    }

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
    }

    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && AppConstants.VoiceOrTouch.vot == 1) {
        // Log.d("Here", "Here");

        ArrayList<String> matches = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        for (String bestMatch : matches) {
            if (bestMatch.contains("stop") || bestMatch.contains("sup")
                    || bestMatch.contains("pop")
                    || bestMatch.contains("map")) {
                Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RecordingDetailsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(my, 0);
                break;
            }

            else if (bestMatch.contains("Pause")
                    || bestMatch.contains("false")
                    || bestMatch.contains("fox")
                    || bestMatch.contains("post")
                    || bestMatch.contains("font")) {

                // Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                // PathRecorderPause.class);
                // startActivityForResult(my, 0);
                break;
            }

            else {
                // Log.i(TAG, "COMMAND_NOT_MATCHING");
            }

        }
    }

    else if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA) {
        // missing data, install it
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent
                .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }

    try {
        mMockGpsProviderTask.cancel(true);
        mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("mMockGpsProviderTask", e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager
                .removeTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("LocationManager", e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mShaker.resume();
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mShaker.pause();
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();

    try {
        mMockGpsProviderTask.cancel(true);
        mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager
                .removeTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

private class MockGpsProvider extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "GpsMockProvider";
    public static final String GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER = "GpsMockProvider";

    /** Keeps track of the currently processed coordinate. */
    public Integer index = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {
        for (String str : data) {
            if (index < mMockGpsProviderIndex) {
                index++;
                continue;
            }

            publishProgress(index);

            Double latitude = null;
            Double longitude = null;
            Double altitude = null;
            try {
                String[] parts = str.split(",");
                latitude = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
                longitude = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
                altitude = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }

            Location location = new Location(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
            location.setLatitude(latitude);
            location.setLongitude(longitude);
            location.setAltitude(altitude);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

            Log.d(LOG_TAG + "-Inuka", location.toString());

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER,
                    location);

            try {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG + "_Traed", "22222");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG + "_Traed", "22222w");

                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    throw new InterruptedException("");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG + "_Traed", "Exception  " + e.getMessage());
                break;
            }

            index++;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG + "-2Inuka", "onProgressUpdate(): " + values[0]);
        mMockGpsProviderIndex = values[0];
    }
}

public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
    Log.d("TTS", "On Finish()");
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    tts.shutdown();
    tts = null;
}


private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

}
}
```

Comment: My Error is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=GpsMockProvider

Comment: please any one give me a idea

Comment: Please read [ask] and maybe [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Please include the full error message or stacktrace. Please describe the steps you have take to tackle the problem.